# get bytestream output from zebra printer

Tags: objective-c, zebra-printers

I need to be able to get the output from a zebra printer when I give it a command.
In toolbox I send "! U1 getvar "apl" " and it sends the command to the printer and then writes an output to the console.
I've successfully managed to send the command to the printer by converting it to bytes and transferring it. But when I try to read from the printer I get a null stream.

Comment: I downloaded LinkOS earlier and have an iMz320 available but won't be able to personally play with it for another week or two. Have you tried contacting your Zebra rep? Sounds like a dumb question but sometimes their engineers can be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zebra offers an SDK to help communicate with their printers.  You'll find commands in the iOS SDK such as "sendAndWaitForResponse" on the Connection object, which should do what you want: http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html.

In general, Zebra printers support TCP connections so there's no reason you shouldn't be able to write to the printer and read the response.  Perhaps you need to wait briefly after sending the outgoing command before reading the response as network conditions can delay the response.  If you include your code, we might be better able to help.

As a final note - make sure you are appending a new line character (0x0A) to the end of your ZPL string.  The printers will only recognize SGD commands (! U1 commands) if they are terminated with a new line character!

Comment: I could not find the "sendAndWaitForResponse" method for the connection object

Comment: Oops - that might only be in their Java SDK.  You may want to attempt my second suggestion and call 'write' and then sleep a short amount of time to wait for a response.  Again - remember to append a new line (0x0A) to the end of your data!

Comment: I had the newline and I finally got the desired output..but it is weird. Toolbox gives me the following results Received:149 bytes 
apl.
apl.enable : none , Choices: none
apl.framework_version : 1.0 
apl.version : none 
apl.o.
apl.o.graphics_byte_width : 72 , Choices: 0-255

Comment: Thus 149 bytes should be received in xcode I initially get 6 bytes and it only prints out the first line. But then I read again after waiting 5000ms and I get the rest with some blank lines.

Comment: If you have network issues, this could happen.  You could write your own logic to wait until you have received a sufficient amount of characters.  In this case - ! U1 getvar "appl" should return 5 or so lines of data, so you could keep reading the response until you have received 5 newline (0x0A) characters in the response.

Comment: But, again, the Zebra SDK would be the best tool to use, because it already has a lot of status-checking functionality built into it.

Comment: There us a method they included called getMaxTimeoutForRead which returns the maximum time in milliseconds to wait for any data to be received. This is how I knew to use 5000 although I'll try your 5 line method.